# Regular expressions - They are the same regular expressions?

Tags: regex, formal-languages

I have two questions. Are those regular expressions are the same?

(1) b*(ab*)* and (b*a)*b *

(2) b*(aaab*)* and (b*aaa) * b*

I feel like they both create language that have worlds palindrome. Is that right? In the first one, both a's are must and b's are zero or unlimited. The second one is the same. the string aaa is a must in both and b's are zero or unlimited.

Am I right?

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41797205/781723, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2109538/14578, http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/69162/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: you funny man ahah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases, the two regular expressions are not the same (they are different regular expressions), but they *do* describe the same language.  So the answer to both questions (from your exercises?) is "yes".

In the first case the regular expressions describe the language of *any* string of `a`'s and `b`'s.  In the second case you get the language where all `a`'s occur in triples, as the combination `aaa`.  This first language also is described by the regular expression `(a|b)*` (or `(a + b)*`, or `(a U b)*`, I don't know what notation your book uses), and the second language also is described by the regular expression `(aaa|b)*`.

In both cases the languages stay the same if you reverse the elements, and therefore, if you reverse the regular expressions that describe them, they stay the same as well.

Palindromes are words that *themselves* stay the same if you reverse them.  But both languages have elements that are *not* palindromes, like for example the word `aaab`, because `aaab` != `baaa`. So talking about palindromes is not the right argument here.